# <div class="clearfix"></div> HTML convert in XML

Tags: xml, html

I have to convert a HTML sheet into XML. 
How do I write `<div class="clearfix"></div>` in XML?

Comment: The question is not clear, can you elaborate you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no certain tags to write `xml`. To write `<div class="clearfix"></div>` in `xml`, write the same line and save it with file extension of `.xml`. Maybe you are thinking that `xml` is also used to make webpages but this is not the truth. The truth is that `xml` is used to store information. See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ for a tutorial on `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like

[image: <pre><div class="clearfix"></div></pre>]

Source :-
http://html-to-xml-parser.blogspot.com/